# Curly braces for `apply` method of companion objects of traits

Tags: scala

I'm reading some code that looks like this:

```
trait Thingy {
  def apply(d: => Unit): Unit
   ...
}

object Thingy {
  def apply(d: => Unit) = {
    ...
  }
}
```

Where does Odersky in his book edition 3 write about traits and traits having companion objects? His book mostly talks about how classes can have companion objects but not traits. Where is this written?

Also, how would you use `thingy`? I see that it's use like this:

```
Thingy {
   implicit variable => 
   val something = ...
}
```

What is going on in the above? Odersky doesn't seem to write about how curly braces can be used to call the apply method. Is this what is going on? Where is this written?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `object Thingy { override def apply(d: => Unit) = {} }` shouldn't compile. Nothing is overridden.

Comment: you're right!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Chapter 9, section 4 "Writing new control structures", Odersky says (all typos are mine):

> One way in which you can make the client code look a bit more like a built-in control structure is to use curly braces instead of parentheses to surround the argument list. In any method invocation in Scala in which you're passing in exactly one argument, you can opt to use curly braces to surround the argument instead of parentheses.

In Chapter 3, "Step 7" he also talks about `apply`:

> When you apply parentheses surrounding one or more values to a variable, Scala will transform the code into an invocation of a method named `apply` on that variable.

Applying these two rules together results in

```
Thingy { ... }
```

being rewritten into

```
Thingy( ... )
```

and then into

```
Thingy.apply(...)
```

It gets even funnier with implicit parameters. For example, for typeclasses it is common to define an `apply` that looks as follows:

```
trait MyTypeClass[A]
object MyTypeClass {
  def apply[A](implicit inst: MyTypeClass[A]) = inst
}
```

so that the value-expression `MyTypeClass[Int]` desugars into `MyTypeClass.apply[Int](someImplicitlyInjectedInstance)`, and thus is a value of type `MyTypeClass[Int]`. So, both the value `MyTypeClass[Int]` and the type `MyTypeClass[Int]` look exactly the same.

---

On the fact that it is not told explicitly that traits can also have companion objects: there are a lot of things that aren't told explicitly. For example, it was not told explicitly that you can write down type-lambdas in Scala, but it turned out that you actually can.

Comment: What did you mean that "So, both the value MyTypeClass[Int] and the type MyTypeClass[Int] look exactly the same." I think I don't understand how `MyTypeClass` is called. I guess this means that at the call site, you only need to type `MyTypeClass[Int]` and the `inst` argument is implied. Right?

Comment: Correct. You will see `MyTypeClass[Int]` being used as a value. The implicit argument `inst` will be inserted by the compiler automatically, therefore you don't need even one argument list, it's omitted completely.

Comment: Just to review a concept for me... when the callsite calls `MyTypeClass[Int]`, what is it actually doing? I'm not clear what passing a type param to a class or object is actually doing in the call site? Is it calling the apply method too?

Comment: @Jwan622 as I said, it is transformed into `MyTypeClass.apply[Int](someImplicitlyInjectedInstance)`.